# Using multiple delimiters in awk

Tags: awk, command-line, text-processing

I have a file which contain following lines:

```
/logs/tc0001/tomcat/tomcat7.1/conf/catalina.properties:app.env.server.name = demo.example.com
/logs/tc0001/tomcat/tomcat7.2/conf/catalina.properties:app.env.server.name = quest.example.com
/logs/tc0001/tomcat/tomcat7.5/conf/catalina.properties:app.env.server.name = www.example.com
```

In above output I want to extract 3 fields (Number 2, 4 and the last one `*.example.com`). I am getting the following output:

```
cat file | awk -F'/' '{print $3 "\t" $5}'
tc0001   tomcat7.1
tc0001   tomcat7.2
tc0001   tomcat7.5
```

How do I also extract last field with domain name which is after `'='`? How do I use `multiple delimiter` to extract field?

Comment: To answer my question which is same same but different, `awk` was swallowing fields when they were blank which foobarred the field numbering. I changed `-F " "` to `-F "[ ]"` and `awk` didn't swallow the empty fields anymore.

Answer (score 470, accepted):

The delimiter can be a regular expression.

```
awk -F'[/=]' '{print $3 "\t" $5 "\t" $8}' file
```

Produces:

```
tc0001   tomcat7.1    demo.example.com  
tc0001   tomcat7.2    quest.example.com  
tc0001   tomcat7.5    www.example.com
```

Comment: Of course, `cat` process is not required: `awk '...' file`. Also, it would be tidier to use the output field separator: `awk -F'[/=]' -v OFS="\t" '{print $3, $5, $8}'`

Comment: Awk delimiters can be regular expressions... this made my day!

Comment: @das.cyklone: awk can also have several separators, with `|` : ex: `awk -F 'this|that|[=/]' '......'`  (usefull to have words/strings separating things) (note that this keeps the spaces in the fiels between 2 separators. Adding also `|[ \t]+` can be useful, but can make things tricky ... as there are often spaces before and after  'this', this will make 2 extra empty field appear in between the space(s) and 'this')

Comment: I've tried this on 2 different distros and I get the same behavior:
I want to get the port from netstat -ntpl
"netstat -ntpl |sed 's/:/ /' |awk '{print $5}' " works but could do without doulbe piping
This works but I was not expecting the data on field 17:
"netstat -ntpl  |awk -F" |:" '{print $17}'"

Comment: @louigi600 The problem is your delimiter expression `" |:"` is splitting on _every_ space character as well as the colon. Which is why your data is on field 17. If you split on _groups_ of spaces, your port will be in field 5 as expected. `netstat -ntpl | awk -F " *|:" '{print $5}'`

Comment: yes ... this got me what I wanted:  awk -F"[ :]+" '/\/postmaster *$/ {print $5}'

Comment: In case of, delimiters with 2 characters like -- "^|", then how we could handled it.

Comment: @user3040157 : `awk -F'[|^]' '…..'` …. but when you say `"^|"`, do you want to match a pipe at start of line, or actually match caret+pipe in the middle of a line ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: actually match caret+pipe in the middle of a line.

Comment: @user3040157 then why not just `FS = "[|]\\^"`

Answer (score 76):

Good news! `awk` field separator can be a regular expression. You just need to use `-F"<separator1>|<separator2>|..."`:

```
awk -F"/|=" -vOFS='\t' '{print $3, $5, $NF}' file
```

Returns:

```
tc0001  tomcat7.1  demo.example.com
tc0001  tomcat7.2  quest.example.com
tc0001  tomcat7.5  www.example.com
```

Here:

- `-F"/|="` sets the input field separator to either `/` or `=`.
- `-vOFS='\t'` is using the `-v` flag for setting a variable. `OFS` is the default variable for the Output Field Separator and it is set to the tab character. The flag is necessary because there is no built-in for the OFS like `-F`.
- `{print $3, $5, $NF}` prints the 3rd, 5th and last fields based on the input field separator.

---

See another example:

```
$ cat file
hello#how_are_you
i#am_very#well_thank#you
```

This file has two fields separators, `#` and `_`. If we want to print the second field regardless of the separator being one or the other, let's make both be separators!

```
$ awk -F"#|_" '{print $2}' file
how
am
```

Where the files are numbered as follows:

```
hello#how_are_you           i#am_very#well_thank#you
^^^^^ ^^^ ^^^ ^^^           ^ ^^ ^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^
  1    2   3   4            1  2   3    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 10):

Another one is to use the -F option but pass it regex to print the text between left and or right parenthesis `()`.

**The file content:**

```
528(smbw)
529(smbt)
530(smbn)
10115(smbs)
```

**The command:**

```
awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' filename
```

**result:**

```
smbw
smbt
smbn
smbs
```

Using awk to just print the text between `[]`:

Use `awk -F'[][]'`  but  `awk -F'[[]]'` will not work.

http://stanlo45.blogspot.com/2020/06/awk-multiple-field-separators.html

Comment: Your answer came up in the deletion queue because 9 times out of 10, users with 1 reputation linking to their own blog usually is spam.  But yours is the exception to the rule. The last 10 years of content there is a gold mine, hopefully you have a plan to immortalize it.

Answer (score 6):

If your whitespace is consistent you could use that as a delimiter, also instead of inserting `\t` directly, you could set the output separator and it will be included automatically:

```
< file awk -v OFS='\t' -v FS='[/ ]' '{print $3, $5, $NF}'
```

Comment: you can skip the `-v ` portion by placing both `FS=..` and `OFS=…` on the right of the code block (the same place where data files are listed). Despite it being on the RHS, their assignment would still be in time for first data row, since you don't have a `BEGIN { }` block that requires additional handling of them.

Answer (score 5):

For a field separator of any number `2` through `5` or letter `a` or `#` or a space, where the separating character must be repeated at least 2 times and not more than 6 times, for example:

```
awk -F'[2-5a# ]{2,6}' ...
```

I am sure variations of this exist using ( ) and parameters

Answer (score 3):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'/[\/=]/' -lane 'print "$F[2]\t$F[4]\t$F[7]"' file
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, put the line in the `$_` variable, do not automatically print every line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – perl will automatically split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this example splits on either `/` or `=`
- `-e` execute the perl code

Perl is closely related to awk, however, the `@F` autosplit array starts at index `$F[0]` while awk fields start with $1.

Comment: does `perl` allow end user to create an array named `@F` if the `-a` flag wasn't set ?

Comment: it should since the @F array isn't special

Comment: ahhh thanks. i just thought `perl` might make it more consistent - since var-args for subroutines are auto split into `@_` then wouldn't auto splitting the main input row `$_` also into a scope-dependent `@_` be more intuitive instead of `@F` ?

Answer (score 0):

I see many perfect answers are up on the board, but still would like to upload my piece of code too,

`awk -F"/" '{print $3 "   "  $5  "   "  $7}' sam | sed 's/ cat.* =//g'`

Comment: `print $3 " " $5 " " $7` can be printed just as `print $3, $5, $7`. Also, I don't see the advantage of using awk and then piping to sed. In general, awk can suffice and others answer show that.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -ne '.split(/ <[/=]> /).[2,4,7].put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
/logs/tc0001/tomcat/tomcat7.1/conf/catalina.properties:app.env.server.name = demo.example.com
/logs/tc0001/tomcat/tomcat7.2/conf/catalina.properties:app.env.server.name = quest.example.com
/logs/tc0001/tomcat/tomcat7.5/conf/catalina.properties:app.env.server.name = www.example.com
```

Sample Output:

```
tc0001 tomcat7.1  demo.example.com
tc0001 tomcat7.2  quest.example.com
tc0001 tomcat7.5  www.example.com
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, input in read linewise with the `-ne` (linewise, non-autoprinting) commandline flags. Lines are `split` on a regex which consists of a custom character class (`/=`) created with the `<[` `]>` operator. Elements `[2,4,7]` are then `put` to give the results above.

Of course, the above is a 'bare-bones' implementation, and Raku being a Perl-family language, TMTOWTDI applies. So lines can be `split` on literal characters separated by a `|` "OR" operator. Element numbering (which is zero-indexed in both Perl and Raku) can be tightened up adding the `:skip-empty` adverb to the `split` routine. Whitespace can be `trim`-med away from each element (using `map`), and the desired elements (now `[1,3,6]`) are `join`-ed with `\t` tabs, giving the following result:

```perl
raku -ne '.split(/ "/" | "=" /, :skip-empty).map(*.trim).[1,3,6].join("\t").put;' file
tc0001  tomcat7.1   demo.example.com
tc0001  tomcat7.2   quest.example.com
tc0001  tomcat7.5   www.example.com
```

https://raku.org