# Processing 2 files with different field separators using awk

Tags: awk

Let's say I have 2 files :

```
$ cat file1
A:10
B:5
C:12

$ cat file2
100 A
50 B
42 C
```

I'd like to have something like :

```
A 10 100
B 5 50
C 12 42
```

I tried this :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{FS=" ";print $2,a[$2],$1}' file1 file2
```

Which outputs me that :

```
  100 A
B 5 50
C 12 42
```

I guess the problem comes from the Field Separator which is set too late for the second file. How can I set different field separator for different files (and not for a single file) ?

Thanks

---

Edit: a more general case

With file2 and file3 like this :

```
$ cat file3
A:10 foo
B:5 bar 
C:12 baz
```

How to get :

```
A 10 foo 100
B 5 bar 50
C 12 baz 42
```

Comment: One option, not necessarily the best, is to preprocess one of the files so it has the same delimiter as the other, and then process them 'naturally' with the single delimiter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWK multiple delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12204192/608639)

Comment: @jww It's not. This question is about how to have different delimiters for different files (not a single file) and the answer is different.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just set FS between files:

```
awk '...' FS=":" file1 FS=" " file2
```

i.e.:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $2,a[$2],$1}' FS=":" file1 FS=" " file2
A 10 100
B 5 50
C 12 42
```

Comment: ahhh nice, that's what I was looking for !

Comment: Yes this is what setting variables in the file list is for - populating initial values differently for different files. For anything else, you're better off setting them up front using `-v`.

Comment: did not realize FS could be used instead of -F like this

Answer (score 1):

You need to get awk to re-split `$0` after you change FS.

You can do that with `$0=$0` (for example).

So `{FS=" ";$0=$0;...}` in your final block will do what you want.

Though only doing that the first time you need to change FS will likely perform slightly better for large files.

Comment: @jeanrjc It worked here. What version of `awk` are you using? Did the output change at all when you did that?

Comment: Nothing changed. I'm on a BSD version of awk (Mac user)

Comment: @jeanrjc You ran `awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{FS=" ";$0=$0;print $2,a[$2],$1}' file1 file2` and still got your original output?

Comment: yes ! (I copy-pasted what you wrote, and still the same output)

Comment: That's odd. You could try saving `$1`, setting it to something else and then setting it back to the saved value. That might force the re-split in a way that `$0=$0` doesn't but I don't know. You could also try `$1=$1` instead of `$0=$0` and see if that works.

Comment: Do not even bother to try `$1=$1` as that recompiles the current record using the value of OFS, not FS. Assigning `$0=$0` IS the correct way to cause the record to be resplit using the current `FS` value. If that doesn't do that for the OP then his awk is broken.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the correction on `$1=$1`. Also for the confirmation that `$0=$0` should work (even in BSD awk).

Comment: @EdMorton : That's odd. I tried on another computer (still Mac), and it still doesn't work. Does it work on a Mac computer for you ?

Comment: I don't have a Mac. The default awk on Macs is broken in other ways so maybe it's broken in this way too?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
$ cat f1
A:10
B:5
C:12
```

```
$  cat f2
100 A
50 B
42 C
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($0,tmp,/:/);a[tmp[1]]=tmp[2];next}$2 in a{print $2,a[$2],$1}' f1 f2
A 10 100
B 5 50
C 12 42
```

or set multiple field separators

```
$ awk -F"[: ]" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$2 in a{print $2,a[$2],$1}' f1 f2
A 10 100
B 5 50
C 12 42
```

Comment: `2 in a` is not the same as his original script. It will omit output that the original would have produced when `file2` contains lines that do not appear in `file1`.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thats correct, but it's often the right way when these kind of implementations are pursued. OP didn't specify if he wanted to keep the lines or not, but I appreciate your feedback as it could help OP make the decision to either leave it or remove it as he feels fit.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you meant, but both file have same keys (`A`,`B,`C`). With the multiple field sperator, won't it be a problem if there is `:`  in the second file ?

Comment: @jeanrjc Yes there would be a problem. In your sample data, you don't seem to list that clearly that multiple field separators are present in **both** files. I would recommend you adding some sample data that truly represents your files.

Comment: Ok, and can you explain `$2 in a` ?

Comment: @jeanrjc That checks whether the value of `$2` is in the array `a` and then only prints out the line if that is true. So, as I indicated in my first comment, it will only print out lines from `file2` when their second field also appeared in the first field of `file1`.

Comment: the split solution works fine with my real data, the file3 was more because I wanted a more general solution.

Comment: @jeanrjc Store `$0` in the `a` array and then print out `$0 a[t[2]]` in the second block?