# Matching two fields between two files AWK

Tags: awk

trying to match fields 1,3 to fields 1,2 in another file and print line of second file. First file is tab delimited and second is csv delimited.   Unexpected token error?
file1

```
1 x 12345 x x x
```

file2

```
1,12345,x,x,x
```

**script**

```
awk -F',' FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1,$3; next} ($1,$2 in a) {print}' file1 file2 > output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

same idea, but doesn't depend on uniqueness of the first field but the pair instead

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$3]; next} ($1,$2) in a' file1 FS=, file2

1,12345,x,x,x
```

Comment: beat me to it ++ ;)

Comment: `^1` Nice use of setting FS between files.

Answer (score 1):

You almost nailed it !

```
awk 'NR==FNR{first[$1]=$3;next} $1 in first{if(first[$1]==$2){print}}' file1 FS="," file2
```

**Output**

```
1,12345,x,x,x
```

**Notes**

1. Since the field separator is different for both the files, we have changed it in between files.
2. This script makes an assumption that the first field of each file is unique, else, the script breaks

   ---

<sup>See [[ switching field separator ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24517482/1620779)  in between files.</sup>

Comment: The switching of FS was classy. ;)

Comment: I borrowed the technique from [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24517482/1620779) answer.

Comment: Still having issues... Do I need to add -F',' argument?

Comment: @mxttgen31 What is the issue? Could you add more sample input and expected output?

Comment: the FS="," did it! Thanks!

Comment: @mxttgen31  you may consider accepting the other solution as it doesn't require the first field to be unique