# How to use multiple delimiters in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to split up a variable using awk by a colon, but only the last variable.

From this input:

```
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0     tcp dpt:22
```

I want the following output:

```
 protocol=tcp source=0.0.0.0/0 destination=0.0.0.0/0 port=22
```

This is my awk command now:

```
 awk '/^ACCEPT/ {print "protocol=",$2, "source=",$4,"destination=",$5,"port=",$7}"
```

Which produces:

```
protocol=tcp source=0.0.0.0/0 destination=0.0.0.0/0 port=dpt:22
```

But I want to get `22` out of `$7` and not `dpt:22`

I've tried using awk's field separator, but I can figure out how to make it only apply to a single variable

Comment: There's no semicolon. `:` is colon, `;` is semicolon.

Comment: Have you tried using the `split()` function? The name is right there in your question title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWK multiple delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12204192/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tweak FS to include the :

```
$ echo 'ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0     tcp dpt:22' |
     awk '/^ACCEPT/{printf("protocol=%s source=%s destination=%s port=%s\n", $2,$4,$5,$8)}
     ' FS='[ :]*'
protocol=tcp source=0.0.0.0/0 destination=0.0.0.0/0 port=22
```

You might need to include tabs, and do `FS='[ :\t]*'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to define a custom field separators in `awk`.

```
some_command | awk -F '[[:blank:]:]+' '/^ACCEPT/{
   printf "protocol=%s source=%s destination=%s port=%s\n", $2, $4, $5, $NF}'

protocol=tcp source=0.0.0.0/0 destination=0.0.0.0/0 port=22
```

`-F '[[:blank:]:]+'` sets input field separator as one of white-space or colon.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following **awk** approach:

```
awk '{ printf "protocol=%s source=%s destination=%s port=%s\n",$2,$4,$5,substr($7,5) }' file
```

---

But if the last field has dynamic *prefix* length you may apply `gsub()` function to remove non-digit characters:

```
awk '{ gsub(/^[^0-9]+/,"",$7); printf "protocol=%s source=%s destination=%s port=%s\n",$2,$4,$5,$7 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

slight modification in your **awk** command

```
$ awk '/^ACCEPT/ {gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$7); print "protocol="$2, "source="$4,"destination="$5,"port="$7}' file
protocol=tcp source=0.0.0.0/0 destination=0.0.0.0/0 port=22
```

`gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$7);` will nullify all non-digit characters in `$7`

Answer (score 0):

awk has a `split` function to break a string (argument 1) up into an array of fields (argument 2) using a specified delimiter regexp (argument 3).

The following awk program will scan all the iptables options (field 6 through the last field of the line), rather than relying on dpt:### being the 7th field.

```
awk '/^ACCEPT/ {
                 port="???"
                 for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) {
                   if (split($i, opt, ":")==2 && opt[1]=="dpt") {
                      port=opt[2]
                   }
                 }
                 print "protocol=" $2, "source=" $4, "destination=" $5, "port=" port
               }'
```