# Splitting columns using awk

Tags: awk

Hi I tried to split columns using `awk` command where in I have to use two separate characters for splitting the same column  "comma and colon"

If My input file is like this

```
 0/1:121,313:4:99:123,0,104
```

I used : to split the column

```
echo "0/1:121,313:4:99:123,0,104" | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[2] a[3]}
```

I am getting this output

```
121,3134
```

However I only Need this output

```
121313
```

How to separate using both : and , ( Colon and Comma)

And I dont want to use `awk -F` command cause this is part of larger tab delimited text file which I am workin on.

Comment: there's a duplicate somewhere... will try to search.. answer is to use regex character class

Comment: if you need to use split instead of `-F` for reasons not mentioned in question, change `":"` to `/[,:]/`

Comment: and more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50142163/use-awk-with-two-different-delimiters-to-split-and-select-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks Sundeep. You can put your answer in answer section so that the answer is visible clearly.

Comment: @RonicK I didn't answer as such questions are closed as duplicates..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
awk -F '[,:]' '{ print $2 $3 }' file
```

By setting the field separator (by means of `-F`) to "either `,` or `:`", we may avoid doing an explicit `split()` on the data.

Or,

```
awk -F '[,:]' '{ print $2, $3 }' OFS='' file
```

which additionally uses an empty output field separator.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted mine to not answer a blatantly duplicate question

Comment: how to update in the file