# Can I use a different delimiter in different code blocks in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

In AWK can i set up multiple delimiter in action , like below example

```
BEGIN { Actions}
{ACTION-1} # here delimiter will be comma ","
{ACTION-2} # here delimiter will be colon":"
{ACTION-1} # here delimiter will be space " "
END { Actions }
```

Comment: Are you matching three differently-formatted lines? What does the input data this is in reference to look like? (If you want to take the result of splitting on one delimiter, and then split *one of those fields* on another, that's a bit clearer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWK multiple delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12204192/608639)

Comment: Flagged for reopening. This question is about using different delimiters for different blocks. The linked question is about using multiple alternative delimiters in the same block. This is a subtle difference, but it may be important. (and the answers will be different)

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12204192/608639. It's not a great question since it's missing sample input/output but it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, but what you can do instead is explicitly split the line you're looking at. That would be:

```
{ split($0, parts, ","); ACTION-1 }
{ split($0, parts, ":"); ACTION-2 }
{ split($0, parts, " "); ACTION-1 }
```

This way you get the values you're after, but they're accessible as `parts[1], parts[2], ...` rather than `$1, $2, ...`.

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can:

```
BEGIN { Actions}
{FS=","; $0=$0; ACTION-1} # here delimiter will be comma ","
{FS=":"; $0=$0; ACTION-2} # here delimiter will be colon":"
{FS=" "; $0=$0; ACTION-1} # here delimiter will be space " "
END { Actions }
```

Assigning anything to `$0` causes awk to re-do field splitting using the current value of `FS` so the fact it had already split the record into fields before then is irrelevant.

Having said that - there's almost certainly a better approach to whatever it is you're trying to do.