# how to count number of fields for a single column in a row separated by 2 field separators (":" and ",")?

Tags: awk

given the text file:
(the structure is: "group_name:pw:group_id:user1<,user2>...")

```
adm:x:4:syslog,adm1
admins:x:1006:adm2,adm12,manuel
ssl-cert:x:122:postgres
ala2:x:1009:aceto,salvemini
conda:x:1011:giovannelli,galise,aceto,caputo,haymele,salvemini,scala,adm2,adm12
adm1Group:x:1022:adm2,adm1,adm3
docker:x:998:manuel
```

how can i count the number of users for every line? or for a single line?

for example, if i want to know how many users contains the "*adm1Group*", the output should be **3**, because *adm1Group* has **three** users (*adm2, adm1 and adm3*). another example, the first line (group name "*adm*"), contains two users, *syslog* and *adm1*.

the main problem is that there are two field separators here, so how can i separate the $4 column inside the same awk command? i have this solution by me but here i use two different awk commands linked with a pipe, like this (and i don't know if this is correct or "legal" for the kernel):

```
awk -F: '/adm1Group/ {print $4}' file.txt | awk -F, 'BEGIN {printf "N. of users in adm1Group = "} {print NF}'
```

can i achieve a solution like this in a single awk command? if not, can i use this? or this solution is "bad practice"?

Comment: This StackOverflow question might be very useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204192/using-multiple-delimiters-in-awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. This will print total number of users present in each group name for your Input_file.

```
awk -F':' '
{
  num=0
  arr1[$1]=num=split($NF,arr2,",")
}
END{
  for(i in arr1){
    print "Group " i " has " arr1[i] " users."
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -F':' '                          ##Starting awk program where setting field separator as : here.
{
  num=0                              ##Setting num as 0 here.
  arr1[$1]=num=split($NF,arr2,",")   ##Creating arr1 array with index of $1 and has value of num, which contains total number of total elements in arr2 with delimiter of , here.
}
END{                                 ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i in arr1){                    ##Traversing through arr1 here.
    print "Group " i " has " arr1[i] " users."  ##printing group name and its value(how many times users came for that group).
  }
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: yes, this works perfectly, but could you please explain just the second line of the 1st awk block? there is like a "double" assignment (arr=num=split(..)), can we simplify that line maybe in two separated lines ?

Comment: @sirducas, yeah I am going to add detailed explanation in a min or so.

Comment: @sirducas, I have added detailed explanation for my code above, let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: so, the split function always return an integer, or it returns an integer only in this scenario because we are using $NF?

Comment: @sirducas, so this is how it works: `split($NF,arr2,",")` function splits last column($NF) into array arr2 where delimiter in $NF is `,` and `num` is total number of elements of array of arr2 OR in other language you can say all elements values of users separated by `,` in last field(num contains that), which(num) is further assigned to value of arr1. Let me know in case of any queries cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> how can i count the number of users for every line? or for a single
> line?

I would use GNU `AWK` to count number of `,` inside 4th field and increase it by `1`, let `file.txt` content be

```
adm:x:4:syslog,adm1
admins:x:1006:adm2,adm12,manuel
ssl-cert:x:122:postgres
ala2:x:1009:aceto,salvemini
conda:x:1011:giovannelli,galise,aceto,caputo,haymele,salvemini,scala,adm2,adm12
adm1Group:x:1022:adm2,adm1,adm3
docker:x:998:manuel
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{printf "N of users in %s is %s\n", $1, gsub(/,/,"",$4)+1}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
N of users in adm is 2
N of users in admins is 3
N of users in ssl-cert is 1
N of users in ala2 is 2
N of users in conda is 9
N of users in adm1Group is 3
N of users in docker is 1
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is `:`. For each line I do use `printf` which acts like fill template and print and for filling I use 1st field (`$1`) and number of changes [`gsub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function done when ordered to replace `,` using empty string (`""`) at 4th field (`$4`) increased by 1 (as last name has not trailing `,`). Note that this does alter `$4` (delete `,` characters) but for this task said side effect is irrelevant. Note that when using `printf` you need to provide newline character (`\n`) implicitly, as opposed to `print`.

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)

Comment: a clean solution to use gsub! However, you might want to replace it with `,` instead of `""` if the user wants to reuse `$4` again in its original form.

Comment: yes this was my first thought as solution, but I have encountered a problem with strings that have no user, i.e. the case where this command should output zero. (I know it may be impossible since each user is assigned to a group, but theoretically speaking it is possible with other non-user data), the output would always be 1 in that case, because of the +1, right? or am I wrong ?

Comment: @sirducas yes for empty column number given would be `1`, but this is might be compensated using ternary operator, for example `{n=gsub(/,/,"",$4);printf "N of users in %s is %s\n", $1, n==0?0:n+1}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` for this:

```bash
awk -F: '$1 == "adm1Group" {print split($NF, a, /,/)}' file
3


awk -F: '$1 == "conda" {print split($NF, a, /,/)}' file
9
```

Or to print all of them together:

```bash
awk -F: '{print split($NF, a, /,/), "no of users in adm1Group:", $1}' file

2 no of users in adm1Group: adm
3 no of users in adm1Group: admins
1 no of users in adm1Group: ssl-cert
2 no of users in adm1Group: ala2
9 no of users in adm1Group: conda
3 no of users in adm1Group: adm1Group
1 no of users in adm1Group: docker
```

Comment: conda has 9 users, right? i'm just looking for the split built-in function because i never use that

Comment: Yes of course `9`. It was a typo earlier. If it worked out please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:` **or** `,` as the field separator, then print the number of fields minus the 3 leading ones:

```bash
awk -F'[:,]' '{print $1, NF - 3}' file
```

```bash
awk -F'[:,]' -v group=conda '$1 == group {print NF - 3}' file
```

Comment: i like this solution and its working, however this command is restricted to this file text, with this particular structure, am i right? for example, if i don't know the exact number of fields between the name group and the user list, is this command still working?

Comment: You're correct, the hardcoded `3` is a problem for variable file formats. If you know that the comma-separated field is the last one, then use one of the `split` solutions given.

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g}awk '$!NF=sprintf("%20s\47s user(s) count = %\0478.f",$!_,NF-!_)' FS=':.+:|,'

          adm's  user(s) count =         2
       admins's  user(s) count =         3
     ssl-cert's  user(s) count =         1
         ala2's  user(s) count =         2
        conda's  user(s) count =         9
    adm1Group's  user(s) count =         3
       docker's  user(s) count =         1
```

And with a tiny bit of modification, now the full list of users will be available at the tail. specifically, the tiny bolded item - now it's overwriting `$1` instead of `$0` ::

`{m,g}awk '` **`$!_`**  `= sprintf("%15s\47s user(s) count = %\0476.f",$!_,NF-!_)' FS=':.+:|,'`

```
        adm's user(s) count =      2 syslog adm1
     admins's user(s) count =      3 adm2 adm12 manuel
   ssl-cert's user(s) count =      1 postgres
       ala2's user(s) count =      2 aceto salvemini
      conda's user(s) count =      9 giovannelli galise aceto caputo haymele salvemini scala adm2 adm12
  adm1Group's user(s) count =      3 adm2 adm1 adm3
     docker's user(s) count =      1 manuel
```

Comment: Why do you write `!NF` instead of `0` and `!_` instead of `1`?

Comment: @jarno : cuz `mawk`s sometimes act up when assign a number only to `$0`, while assigning to `$1 = $0 = …` is overly verbose  - `$!NF` is the way to circumvent that issue.

Comment: Oh, I guess it is a bug in `mawk`, then.

Comment: @jarno : actually all have this, actually, by design :  `echo 'abc' | gawk '$_ = 0'` prints absolutely nothing, because the "pattern" evaluated to false thanks to that 0. However, `echo 'abc' | gawk '$_ = "0"'` prints the `"0"` as desired since it's a non-empty `ASCII` string that happens to contain the digit "0" instead of being a number.

Comment: @jarno : the safest way to guarantee printing regardless of what's being assigned, is to take the 0th-power of the entire expression - it could be positive INFinity, negative NaN, or a string of 5 emojis, doesn't matter - 0-th power in `awk` always yields a 1

Comment: Similarly `echo 'abc' | gawk '$0 = 0'` prints nothing and `echo 'abc' | gawk '$0 = "0"'` prints "0" so I do not see the point in the obscure way of telling the index.

Comment: @jarno : it's merely a style preference of mine that's all. you're free to pick whatever works for u