# bash script to extract text from user's env.php?

Tags: mysql, bash

I work for a web-hosting company. I'm rather green, and being new, I only have non-root access to our clients' servers. Often, I need to troubleshoot mysql. Since I don't have root, I must use the clients' mysql credentials. These can be found in

```
~/<domain>/html/app/etc/env.php
```

an example block:

```
'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'xxxxx',
                'username' => 'xxxxx',
                'password' => 'xxxxx',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [
                    1014 => false
```

I need to extract dbname, username, and password from this block of the file on each unique server. Until now, I've just been using cat, but since each server has its env.php in a unique path (based on domain name) I don't know how to do this in a one-shot. Using find to search ~/ for env.php doesn't work since clients will often copy their site for backup and dev purposes, creating multiple files with that name.

My bash is very basic. Any tips are appreciated and will make my work much more efficient.

Until now, I have been moving into the site directories manually and navigating to the file I need. This is time consuming.

Edit: using basic grep to find these fields in the file doesn't work since it returns credentials from all blocks (redis, etc), and not just the mysql username/password.

Comment: I would write a PHP program, which reads env.php (trivial, as this is php code already) and writes to stdout the information you need. Than you write a bash program which runs this php script and catches its stdout.

Comment: We need more information to help you. We need a.o. a sample of the information contained in env.php. Put several blocks, without posting confidential information obviously. We also to need how the output must look like. And finally, you have to provide at least some lines of code you wrote, even if it not doing what you want.

Comment: What we need in fact is a minimal reproducible example. I advise you to learn how to post something like that in SO (StackOverflow).

Comment: Write a short PHP script that includes `env.php` and prints what you need from it, in whatever format you need. Anything else (bash, sed, grep, awk, perl, python etc) is just too complicate and very error prone.

Comment: @procyon108 what identifies the block as being the one you want? do you use the block that has a known `dbname` value, or is `db` unique? If the block can be unambiguously identified, extracting particular entries from the block is fairly straightforward using `awk`

Answer (score 0):

One `grep` solution that depends on the format of the 'db' configuration blocks matching your example would be to use grep's `-B` switch to ask for 3 lines preceding the line that matches `=> 'mysql[0-9]*'`.   This assumes that the 3 lines preceding are the 'dbname, username, and password'.  Thus, this could be fairly fragile.

```
 grep -B 3 "=> 'mysql[0-9]*'" /path/to/your/env.php | grep 'dbname\|username\|password'
                'dbname' => 'xxxxx',
                'username' => 'xxxxx',
                'password' => 'xxxxx',
```

Another option (that will likely be much less fragile) would be to use `awk`:

```
awk -F'=>' '/^'\''db'\'' => \[/ {flag=1} /dbname|password|username/ && flag==1 {gsub(/'\''|,/,""); print $2} /^\]/ && flag==1 {flag=0}' /path/to/your/env.php 
 xxxxx
 xxxxx
 xxxxx
```

This awk command will explicitly look inside the db configuration block for the dbname, password and username lines and then print the values for those configurations. The command will also strip the single quotes and trailing commas from the output.

Answer (score 0):

[`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) can be a great addition to your toolbox, as you can specify things like range toggles and blocks to execute. For example -

```
$: sed -En "/^'db' *=>/,/]/{ /'connection' *=>/,/]/{ /'(dbname|username|password)' *=>/p }; }" file
            'dbname' => 'xxxxx',
            'username' => 'xxxxx',
            'password' => 'xxxxx',
```

Obviously, `awk` is great for a more programmatic solution, but someone already addressed that.

Comment: Horrible! Not even close to a generic solution. This solution expects certain operators or other syntax elements to be on the same line as the "main" keyword and/or expects the lines to be ordered in a specific way. If a sed solution were remotely viable for this problem, it would begin by tokenizing all the elements in the env.php file. But at least you don't trust user input and avoid eval at all costs in bash oneliners, so there is that :D. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that the file is source code and is likely to be delimited by single or double quotes.

Given:

```
$ \cat env.php 
<?php return [
  "memcache" => [
    "count" => "1",
    "host1" => "cluster.memes.db.example.com",
    "port1" => "1111",
    "password" => "f1313123",
  ],
  "mysql" => [
    "database" => "my_db",
    "host" => "server.mysql.eu.company.example.net",
    "password" => "J[VwNWJISuUGx09RI2hn6",
    "port" => "3306",
    "user" => "my_user",
  ],
  "redis" => [
    "count" => "1",
    "host1" => "redis.example.tld",
    "port1" => "1231",
    "password" => "EEEEEEE",
  ],
]
```

So the essential clue is:

```
$ <env.php  awk '-F"' '{ print $2, $4}'
 
memcache 
count 1
host1 cluster.memes.db.example.com
port1 1111
password f1313123
 
mysql 
database my_db
host server.mysql.eu.company.example.net
password J[VwNWJISuUGx09RI2hn6
port 3306
user my_user
 
redis 
count 1
host1 redis.example.tld
port1 1231
password EEEEEEE
```

You may have to do some preprocessing, like convert all " to ' or vice versa.
And probably some post-processing for comfort:

```
$ <env.php  awk '-F"' '{ print $2, $4}' \
   | tr \  = \
   | sed -n '/mysql=/,$p' \
   | sed -E '/(redis|memcached|mailchimp)/q'
mysql=
database=my_db
host=server.mysql.eu.company.example.net
password=J[VwNWJISuUGx09RI2hn6
port=3306
user=my_user
=
redis=
```

Obviously you need to adjust `mysql=` -> `db=` for your case.
And it's possible to be clever in the awk script about which fields you print, but this should get you started, I believe.

With your input I get:

```
$ <env2.php  awk "-F'" '{ print $2, $4, $6, $8, $10, $12 }' | tr \  = | sed -n '/db=/,$p' | sed -E '/(redis|memcached|mailchimp)/q'
db=====
table_prefix=====
connection=====
default=====
host=localhost====
dbname=xxxxx====
username=xxxxx====
password=xxxxx====
model=mysql4====
engine=innodb====
initStatements=SET=NAMES=utf8;====
active=1====
driver_options=====
=====
```

Pro Tip: ask someone who has worked there for a while how they do it. You might be in for a pleasant surprise!

Comment: and awk supports regex as a separator: `echo " \"key\" => 'val' " | awk "-F\"|'" '{ print $2"="4 }'` -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204192/using-multiple-delimiters-in-awk -- what a time to be alive!